# Como inserir uma lista de dados usando o volley

Tags: android, restful, volley

Minha aplicação grava todos as informações de posições dentro da tabela posicoesdados.
Essa tabela tem uma coluna chamada "ENVIADO".

Eu tenho que fazer um select retornando todas as posições que não foram enviadas e mandar para um webserver, após enviar e o resultado for OK, eu preciso setar o flag para TRUE, enviado.

Tenho 2 problemas.

1 - Usando o volley, ele envia somente a ultima posição, pois quando faço:

```
for (DadosPosicao dadosposicao : dadosposicoes) {
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_DISPOSITIVO, app.getSistema().getDispositivoID());
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getLatitude()));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getLatitude()));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_DTLOG, Funcoes.formatarDataHora(dadosposicao.getDtlog(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_DTRECEBIMENTO, Funcoes.formatarDataHora(dadosposicao.getDtRecebimento(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_PANICO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getPanico() ? 1 : 0));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_VELOCIDADE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getVelocidade()));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_HODOMETRO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getHodometro()));
    params.put(Constantes.KEY_DIRECAO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getDirecao()));

}
```

Eu entendi que ele sobrepoe as minhas KEY. :(

2 - Como eu sei que aquela posição foi enviada com sucesso para poder mudar o flag pra true?

Hoje tenho o seguinte:

```
public void EnviarPosicoes() {

    if (isOnline()) {
        LocalDao<DadosPosicao> dadosPosicaoDao = LocalFactoryDB.getDao(this, DadosPosicao.class);

        final List<DadosPosicao> dadosposicoes = ((DadosPosicaoLocalDao) (dadosPosicaoDao))
                .selectDadosPosicaoNaoEnviados();

        if (dadosposicoes.size() > 0) {
            StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, servidor,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("mrcsistemas", response);
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                    Log.i(Constantes.TAG, app.getSistema().getDispositivoID());

                    for (DadosPosicao dadosposicao : dadosposicoes) {
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_DISPOSITIVO, app.getSistema().getDispositivoID());
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getLatitude()));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getLatitude()));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_DTLOG, Funcoes.formatarDataHora(dadosposicao.getDtlog(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_DTRECEBIMENTO, Funcoes.formatarDataHora(dadosposicao.getDtRecebimento(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_PANICO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getPanico() ? 1 : 0));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_VELOCIDADE, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getVelocidade()));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_HODOMETRO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getHodometro()));
                        params.put(Constantes.KEY_DIRECAO, String.valueOf(dadosposicao.getDirecao()));

                    }

                    return params;
                }
            };

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(postRequest);

        }
    }
}
```

Minha duvida, qual a meneira correta de fazer para enviar a minha lista de aproximadamente 10 posições?
Como sei que a posição foi enviada com sucesso?

Answer (score 1):

Estão sobrepondo sim sua key, no caso você pode tentar enviar da seguinte forma.

```
for(int i =0;i<dadosposicoes.lenght;i++){
params.put(Constantes.KEY_LATITUDE+i, dadosposicoes.get(i).getLatitude());
//outros params...}
```

para recuperar é so voce fazer um for e pegar por posicao.

o correto mesmo seria você trabalhar com JSON, a lib volley da suporte. seus dados em JSON seria algo bem semelhante a isso:

```
{
"dados": [
    {
        "dispositivo_id":"xxx-yyy",
        "Latitude":"xxxx",
        "longitude":"xxxx",
        "data_recebimento":"xxxx",
        "panico":"xxxx",
        "velocidade":"xxxx",
        "hodometro":"xxxx",
        "direcao":"xxxx"
    },
    {
        "dispositivo_id":"xxx-yyy",
        "Latitude":"xxxx",
        "longitude":"xxxx",
        "data_recebimento":"xxxx",
        "panico":"xxxx",
        "velocidade":"xxxx",
        "hodometro":"xxxx",
        "direcao":"xxxx"
    },
    {
        "dispositivo_id":"xxx-yyy",
        "Latitude":"xxxx",
        "longitude":"xxxx",
        "data_recebimento":"xxxx",
        "panico":"xxxx",
        "velocidade":"xxxx",
        "hodometro":"xxxx",
        "direcao":"xxxx"
    }
]
```

}

claro é só uma dica.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, estou usando cakephp para ser o webserver.